# AWS Coginto API , Forgot Password Action not raising InvalidParameterException even if neither a verified phone number nor a verified email exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

As per docs says  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html If the user has not yet verified his email or phone number then

```
Auth.forgotPassword(username)
```

should return some error message. as written in documentation

**If neither a verified phone number nor a verified email exists, an InvalidParameterException is thrown.**

but it's not raising an exception, instead, I receive a success response.

```
"CodeDeliveryDetails":{"AttributeName":"email","DeliveryMedium":"EMAIL","Destination":"m***@g***.com"}}
```

I dont receive the email though.

what can be the reason ?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue and unfortunately have not found an answer yet.

Answer (score 8):

I was seeing the same issue. It turned out to the related to this:

*Use the PreventUserExistenceErrors setting of a user pool app client to enable or disable user existence related errors.*

mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-managing-errors.html:

After changing that setting on the user pool to 'Legacy' from 'Enabled' I started seeing a 400 response:

```
{
  "__type": "UserNotFoundException",
  "message": "Username/client id combination not found."
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. I am concerned, though, that Enabled was a "recommended" option.

Answer (score 1):

@ryan-hines Oh my god, thank you! I've been struggling with this for days.

We had a very similar issue:

- User signs up via Google
- User tries to reset password
- We wanted to disallow this and tell them to use their social login (you'd think Cognito would handle this part, but no)

  - In order to solve this, we wrote a custom Migration lambda to handle `"UserMigration_ForgotPassword"`
  - Even though we were throwing an Error in the lambda, it was still showing a success message in the UI, but was not sending the email

In the newer Cognito UI, we had to go into:

- App Integration
- Click on app client
- Click "Edit" in App client information section
- At the bottom under "Advanced security configurations" uncheck "Prevent user existence errors"

Now the UI properly shows a failure when our lambda throws an error.

[image: prevent user existence errors check box]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the email attribute for user is verified